# How do I use a custom JS class with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have an Angular 2 application that I am building using Webpack.  I have a customJS file that incorporates a few things I wanted to do in JS that was easier to do than in Angular.  However, when I try to include this in my project, it has a 404 GET error when I try to load the page.

```
+-- projectName
|   +-- customJS.js
|   +-- app
|   |    +-- Angular 2 ts files
|   +-- dist
|   |    +-- webpackBundle.js
```

And my HTML looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<base href="/projectName/">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="customJS.js"></script>

<link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <myApp></myApp>
</body>
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

<script src="dist/webpackBundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Am I coding this correctly?  Everything else is loaded correctly, just not the customJS code.

Comment: try removing   /projectName/ from base href. Just leave <base href="/" />

Comment: @RRForUI Everything exists under the `projectName` structure, so it is necessary.  All the get calls have to be in the form of `https://my.app.com/projectName/index.html`

Comment: in that case, try adding "~/customJS.js".

Comment: @RRForUI I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webpack, why not just add customJS to the bundle as an export?

```
//customJS.js
<code>
export default SomethingCustom;

//main.js
import SomethingCustom from '../customJS';

SomethingCustom.somethingAwesome();
```